# What elements are involved with songs

Tags: audio

I want to store and write songs.  Are songs all just pitch?  If I stored only the pitch of each part of the song and apply the pitch to a *bing* sound and play it to replicate the song?

I'm very confused.

Comment: Look into [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Instrument_Digital_Interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At minimum you will require a sequence of notes, which have a pitch and duration. This can be improved with chords and other types of polyphony, dynamics (volume or loudness), timbre, etc.

You should look into MIDI technology and related file formats for ideas about such a system, and a possible means for playing your songs on a computer.